# Python - How to shift data to the start of each index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[append two list generated empty row in between, how to remove these unused rows in the dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpO6Y.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your Question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for resetting the index?

```
dataframe = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html